# Basic bouncing ball program, ball won't bounce off wall

Tags: java

So I'm supposed to make a program where a ball bounces around a drawingpanel for 10 seconds. The ball has to bounce off the sides of the panel if it hits them. Right now when the ball hits the bottom panel instead of bouncing it appears in the middle of the screen and moves in the opposite direction until it hits the top and disappears.

I'm pretty sure the problem is in this part of my code...
(Earlier in the code I declared x to 1, y to 250, dx to 1, and dy to 1)

```
//Changes dirction 
public static int newDirection1(int x, int dx, int size){
  if (x < 0 || x > 500 || (x + size) < 0 || (x + size) > 500)  {
    dx *= -1;
    return dx;
  } else {
    return dx;
  } 
} 

//Changes direction 
public static int newDirection2(int y, int dy, int size){
  if (y < 0 || y > 500 || (y + size) < 0 || (y + size) > 500)  {
    dy *= -1;
    return dy;
  } else {
    return dy;
  } 
 } 

 //Moves ball one step
 public static void move(Graphics g, Color color, int size, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){

   g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
   g.fillOval(x1, y1, size, size);
   g.setColor(color);
   g.fillOval(x2, y2, size, size);


 } 

 //Pauses for 10ms
 public static void sleep(int millis, DrawingPanel panel){
   panel.sleep(millis);
 } 


public static void bounceLoop(DrawingPanel panel, Graphics g, Color color, int size, int x, int dx, int y, int dy, int millis){

   int x1 = x + dx;
   int x2 = x + dx;
   int y1 = y + dy;
   int y2 = y + dy;

   for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

     x1 = x + dx * i;
     x2 = (x + dx * i) + dx;
     y1 = y + dy * i;
     y2 = (y + dy * i) + dy;
     dx = newDirection1(x2, dx, size);
     dy = newDirection2(y2, dy, size); 
     move(g, c, size, x1, y1, x2, y2);
     sleep(millis, panel);

   } 
  } 

}
```

Comment: There are lots of examples of this assignment elsewhere in SO, eg question 13022754.  (As an aside, it's curious that you calculate dx and dy and then move without refreshing the values of the new co-ordinates.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the loop don't use:

```
x1 = x + dx * i
```

use

```
x1 = x1 + dx
```

(same for y)
because whenever dx is going to change, and multiply by -1, instead of continuing from where it was, and go to the other direction, it's going to continue from the other side of your panel, or a point that is really off.

Also a few things that could possibly fix the coding:
1- you don't need a dx parameter for your getNewDirection, you only need the coordinate.
2- the boundry conditions may give you errors, give it a small offset that can't be visible to the naked eye to avoid errors with creating objects outside the created panel or whatever you are using

Comment: Thank you, the ball now bounces off the walls. The boundaries have to be 0 and 500, however, the ball is leaving behind arches whenever it hits the walls... is there anyway to get rid of these without changing the boundaries?

Comment: Like i said, try changing the boundaries. Setting them to 4 and 496 for example could solve a few bugs.
Though I have to see the code to understand why it's leaving an arch
It's likely something concerning the loop when reaching boundaries, it may be skipping a certain line that usually removes the ball's previous location.
So instead i suggest you clear the screen at every ball move.